# How to rename multiple dataframes in one loop with a shared dictionary?

Tags: pandas, loops, multiple-columns, rename

I have multiple dataframes which all share the same number of columns with the same names. For some reason, I would like to rename all these columnes with a dictionary.

I know how to do it for one dataframe at a time using the rename function of pandas such as:

```
df = df.rename(columns={"1": "a", etc.})
```

I would like to add a loop for each dataframe from a list of dataframes (df_list) but for some reason it does not act as I would expect it to.

```
df_list = (df1, df2)

for i in df_list:

   i = i.rename(columns={
    '1':'a',
    '2':'b',
    '3':'c', etc.})
```

The code above does not provide any error, nor change anything. Again, both df1 and df2 share the exact same structure (columns = "1", "2", "3", etc.).

I would happily read any suggestion as to how I can proceed to automate the renaming of these columns... Thanks !

Comment: add `inplace=True` in the rename function

Comment: Use a list `df_list = [df1, df2]`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. While moving from a tuple to a list is for sure a good thing, it did not solve my problem alone. Using     inplace = True did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify a tuple, which is immutable. Use a list instead:

```
df_list = [df1, df2]

for i in df_list:

   i = i.rename(columns={
  '1':'a',
  '2':'b',
  '3':'c', ...})
```

Comment: Many thanks, along with inplace=True, this solved my problem.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have? inplace=True should not be required, because you are creating a copy when you assign i = i.rename

Comment: Well, noticed afterwards that indeed, inplace=true is not needed. Just had to apply that to my actual work rather than the example. My pandas version is '0.23.4'. Thanks